# Django manage.py runscript causes EOFError when using input()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a script in Django that generates a report based on user input.

myscript.py

```
def run():
    # analyze some data
    user_input = input('Enter a value:')
    # do secondary analysis based on input value
```

When I execute this script with `python manage.py runscript myscript`, it works until `input()` is called. "Enter a value:" is printed to the console, but instead of waiting for the user to enter a value, the program terminates with `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`. What is going on here?

**Note:** Passing arguments to the script with `--script-args` is not an acceptable workaround because the input value must be determined by the user after the initial data analysis.

**Edit:** Additional Diagnostic Information

Python 3.9.7

Django 3.2.12

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 65, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 77, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 62, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 283, in handle
    run_script(script_mod, *script_args)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/docker-webdev-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 161, in run_script
    exit_code = mod.run(*script_args)
  File "/code/scripts/myscript.py", line 3, in run
    user_input = input('Enter a value:')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: It works just fine for me. Please share the full stack trace for the error. Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I've edited the question to include additional diagnostic information.

Comment: Is the file empty or corrupted?